# Finding a contour within a circle

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm trying to write a program that can detect the straight line cut on the circular lens, as seen on the left side of the image:

[image]

Now, I have tried using Canny edge detection, Hough Line Transform and findContour to separate the line alone, but I have been unsuccessful in doing so.

I have also tried to detect the line by first detecting the outer circle of the lens and performing a contour search within the ROI(detected circle), but I get random lines across the lens but not the output I want.

Comment: Do you wish to locate that region as in defect detection or is it just to draw a line there?

Comment: Just to draw a line on that region. It is not a defect, but just the part where the lens was cut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all I would like to point out that your image is very noisy. Meaning that simply by looking for contours or edges or lines will probably not work because due to noise. This makes a task very difficult. If you are looking for a way to automatize such a task I would suggest to put some effort in finding the right lighting (I think that a classical dome light would suffice) as it would make much less noise on the image (less reflections ...) and hence it would be easier to make such algoritm.

That being said. I have made an example on how I would try to achieve such a task. Note that this solution might not work for other images but in this one example the result is quite good. It will maybe give you a new point of view on how to tackle this problem.

First I would try to perform an histogram equalization before tranforming the image to binary with OTSU threshold. After that I would perform opening (erosion followed by dilation) on the image:

[image]

After that I would make a bounding box over the biggest contour. With x,y,h,w I can calculate the center of bounding box which will serve as my center of the ROI I am going to create. Draw a circle with radius slightly less then w/2 on a copy of the image and a circle on a new mask with the radius equal to w/2. Then perform a bitwise operation:

[image]

Now you have your ROI and have to threshold it again to make the boundary without noise and search for contours:

[image]

Now you can see that you have two contours (inner and outer). So now you can extract the area where the lens is cut. You can do this by calculating distances between every point of the inner contour and outer contour. Formula for distance between 2 points is `sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y2)^2)`. Threshold this distances so that if the distance is less than some integer and draw a line between these two points on the image. I drew the distances with a blue line so. After that tranform the image to HSV colorspace and mask it with bitwise operation again so all that is left are those blue lines:

[image]

Perform an OTSU threshold again and select the biggest contour (those blue lines) and fit a line through the contour. Draw the line on the original image and you will get the ending result:

[image]

Example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

### Perform histogram equalization and threshold with OTSU.
img = cv2.imread('lens.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
equ = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(equ,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

### Perform opening (erosion followed by dilation) and search for contours.
kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, iterations = 2)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

### Select the biggest one and create a bounding box.
### This will be used to calculate the center of your ROI.
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

### Calculate x and y of the center.
x,y,w2,h2 = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
center_x = int(x+(w2/2))
center_y = int(y+(h2/2))

### Create the radius of your inner circle ROI and draw it on a copy of the image.
img2 = img.copy()
radius = int((w2/2)-20)
cv2.circle(img2,(center_x,center_y), radius, (0,0,0), -1)

### Create the radius of your inner circle ROI and draw it on a blank mask.
radius_2 = int(w2/2)
h,w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(mask,(center_x,center_y), radius_2, (255,255,255), -1)

### Perform a bitwise operation so that you will get your ROI
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img2, img2, mask=mask)

### Modify the image a bit to eliminate noise with thresholding and closing.
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(res,190,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel, iterations = 2)

### Search for contours again and select two biggest one.
gray = cv2.cvtColor(closing,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
area = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
contour1 = area[0]
contour2 = area[1]

### Iterate through both contours and calculate the minimum distance.
### If it is less than the threshold you provide, draw the lines on the image.
### Forumula is sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y2)^2).
for i in contour1:
    x = i[0][0]
    y = i[0][1]
    for j in contour2:
        x2 = j[0][0]
        y2 = j[0][1]
        dist = np.sqrt((x2-x)**2 + (y2-y)**2)
        if dist < 12:
            xy = (x,y)
            x2y2 = (x2,y2)
            line = (xy,x2y2)
            cv2.line(img2,xy,x2y2,(255,0,0),2)
        else:
            pass

### Transform the image to HSV colorspace and mask the result.
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img2,img2, mask= mask)

### Search fot contours again.
gray = cv2.cvtColor(res,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

### Fit a line through the contour and draw it on the original image.
[vx,vy,x,y] = cv2.fitLine(cnt, cv2.DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01)
left = int((-x*vy/vx) + y)
right = int(((w-x)*vy/vx)+y)
cv2.line(img,(w-1,right),(0,left),(0,0,255),2)

### Display the result.
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Note that you will have to play a little with the parameters radius of inner circle (maybe change to -30) and the consequently the threshold dist < 12 to maybe 22